# Couple of bootstrap style questions

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

*How to apply alternating color to bootstrap grid system*

```
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label>Row1 Col-1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label>Row1 Col-2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label>Row1 Col-3</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label>Row2 Col-1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label>Row2 Col-2
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></label>
    <label>Row2 Col-3</label>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

*Apply Style site wide*

I have include the bootstrap css in my project. Until I specify 'form-control' to input element the style is not working. How I force all the input elements in my site to inherit style 'form-control'

Answer (score 0):

For your first question you can do this.

```
.row div:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
.row div:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

For your second question you can copy the rules defined in the form-control class and override them into a separate css something like below.

```
input, select {
     RULES FROM FORM CONTROL
}
```